# How to delete all clusters in databricks azure, not searching and copying for cluster_id?

Tags: azure, rest, databricks, azure-databricks

I would like to pragmatically delete set of clusters. Let's say, they are only one purpose for some testing and I'd like to delete them at once.

I thought maybe it is possible, when I assign all clusters to the specific pool, but it seems Pool API does not return info about clusters assigned to it.

Any other ideas?

thx

Comment: did that answer your question? if so, can you please click on the check mark.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that easily in PowerShell using this [module](https://github.com/DataThirstLtd/azure.databricks.cicd.tools). I tested this script below and worked like charm

```
$databricksBearerToken = "" # enter your manually generated token here 
$databricksRegion = "" # enter region for the workspace here 
$databricksWorkSpaceName = "" # enter the name of your databricks workspace

# Return a list of existing clusters
$myclusters = Get-DatabricksClusters -BearerToken $databricksBearerToken -Region $databricksRegion

# Iterate through these clusters and remove them one by one
Foreach($cluster in $myclusters)
{ 
  $clusterName = $cluster.cluster_name
  $clusterID = $cluster.cluster_id
  Write-Host $clusterName
  Remove-DatabricksCluster -BearerToken $databricksBearerToken -Region $databricksRegion -ClusterName $clusterName -ClusterId $clusterID
}
```

Comment: So the solution is, add clusters I want to group to one workspace. Is there any other way? Use tags? regex over name?